# Flask Admin edit able user change their data

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, roles, flask-admin

I'm using **Flask-Admin** to manage my CRUD.
There are three roles in my app, which is **superuser**, **operator** and **client**.

In this app, operators must ask superuser to register their account, to change their data and others.

But for the client which is uncounted numbers, I want they can register their account or editable their account information by own.

For now, the client has can register by own, but now I want the client can editable their information individually without through superuser.

So far, I just can edit the account information by **superuser**, like this screenshot:
[image]

So for now, I want client can edit their name, email, password or other information by their own, but also separate their data with the other clients.

Here is the snippet of my model:

```
roles_users = db.Table(
    'roles_users',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('role_id', db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('role.id'))
)

class Role(db.Model, RoleMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary=roles_users,
                            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

class Operator(User):
    __tablename__ = 'operator'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'))


class Client(User):
    __tablename__ = 'client'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

So, how to do that with **Flask-Admin**..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask-Security comes with a built-in form and view for password change. I would recommend using that. https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Security/customizing.html

to edit user info via Flask-Admin view, you can override these methods by doing the following. Don't forget to add 'client' as accepted role in your flask-admin User class.
The custom filter has to filter on current_user_id, so no other user profile can be editted.

```
def get_query(self) 
    if "superuser" in current_user.roles:
        return self.session.query(self.model)  # as original source code

    else:  # for all other roles
        return self.session.query(self.model).filter(
            < insert custom filter here> )



def get_count_query(self): 
    if "superuser" in current_user.roles:
        return self.session.query(func.count('*')).select_from(self.model) # as original source code

    else: # for all other roles
        return self.session.query(func.count('*')).filter(
            <insert custom filter here>  )
```

An alternative solution would be so build a custom view (without using flask-admin) and call it /myprofile.